# How to "compress" a function on x-axis?

Tags: functions

Let say I've two function like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bfipfoxrxe

[image]

Where the cross the x-axis at 0 and 1. I'd like to move the "1" point, "compressing" the graph, such as they cross x-axis at 0 and 0.5, but keeping the bend.

Somethings like this (sorry for my paint hehe):

[image]

Comment: Substitute $2x$ into the red $y_1$ equation to compress it. In this new equation, substitute $(1-x)$ to get the new version of the green $y_2$ curve.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis sorry don't get it. red one: substitute 2x with what?

Comment: It means, replace all occurrences of $x$ by $2x$.

Comment: Got it. If you answer, you get Accepted :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$y_1(x)=\frac{3(x-1)}{2x-3}$$
To compress it horizontally by a factor of $1/2$ you have to substitute $2x$ for $x$. So you have a new function $y_1'(x)=y_1(2x)$, which is
$$y_1'(x)=\frac{3(2x-1)}{4x-3}$$

You also have a function $y_2$ that is the mirror of $y_1$, reflected through the line $x=\frac12$. That means that $y_2(x)=y_1(1-x)$. You want this to still be the case after the compression, so we have a new version of that function given by $y_2'(x)=y_1'(1-x)$.
$$y_2'(x)=\frac{3(2(1-x)-1)}{4(1-x)-3}=\frac{3(2x-1)}{4x-1}$$